# Long term time series forecasts with small dataset

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a small dataset which has timestamp and temperature values for 6 months(I.e. one temperature value per day). I would like to forecast 2-3 months of temperature.
I would like to know, what kind of models would be suitable for such purpose.

I have used LSTM but the forecasts degrades as I go further  and the data size is pretty small for LSTM to be trained.

Comment: for LSTM to work well, you need lots of data. Did you try ARIMA, AR, OR VAR models?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reinforcement learning, in instance [mbrrl2](https://gitlab.tubit.tu-berlin.de/shoefer/mbrrl2/tree/master) package.

As temperature is very stational dependent variable. You should have at least 1 year, better 2 years, to make some predictions.

Other way to solve this, is having a collection of historical temperatures, clustering them, and matching your dataset with the closest cluster.